# Get the predicted value from LSTM model

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I am new to Tensorflow. While I am learning 'Time series forecasting' on Tensorflow tutorial page, I couldn't find out how to get the predicted value from the trained model, they only show the plots, but didn't output the predicted value. Can someone tell me how to get the predicted value?

Here is the link for the tutorial I am learning,  which uses LSTM.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#recurrent_neural_network

Clear an example here:

The tutorial created a model using

```
lstm_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    # Shape [batch, time, features] => [batch, time, lstm_units]
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True),
    # Shape => [batch, time, features]
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])
```

and then compile the model

```
history = compile_and_fit(lstm_model, wide_window)
```

then plot it by:

```
wide_window.plot(lstm_model)
```

but how can I see the final predicted value?

Answer (score 0):

As the names suggest, you only compile and fit the model, but did not perform predictions using the model. So to see the final predicted value, you should run predict with something like `model.predict()` from Keras, as explain in the [official Keras page](https://keras.io/api/models/model/).